# How to save logs from Theia output channel to a file

Tags: logging, electron, vscode-extensions, theia, theia-ide

VSCode output channels generate log files by default for each output channel created. Need the log file creation part for my Theia application. Is there a way to implement the same in a Theia based application?

I went through documentation, but still puzzled on how to implement the log file creation in my Theia app.